# How to merge multiple rows based on another column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the below dataframe:

```
Postcode    Borough           Neighbourhood
----------------------------------------------
   0        M1B Scarborough   Rouge
   1        M1B Scarborough   Malvern
   2        M1C Scarborough   Highland Creek
   3        M1C Scarborough   Rouge Hill
   4        M1C Scarborough   Port Union
```

I want to combine entries in the Neighbhourhood column each time there is a duplicate entry in the Postcode column. For example, in output, I want 'M1B' entry only once, and 'Rouge' and 'Malvern' in the Neighbourhood column, separated by commas:

```
Postcode
M1B                           Rouge,Malvern
M1C    Highland Creek,Rouge Hill,Port Union
M1E         Guildwood,Morningside,West Hill
M1G                                  Woburn
M1H                               Cedarbrae
```

This is the output I am currently getting but it is a series, not a dataframe and I am missing out the `Borough` column. I used the below code:

```
df=dataframe.groupby('Postcode')['Neighbourhood'].apply(','.join)
df.head()
```

Please help me get all three columns inside a dataframe, not a series.

Comment: Use `df = df.groupby('Postcode').agg({'Neighbourhood':', '.join})`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df=dataframe.groupby(['Postcode', 'Borough']).Neighbourhood.apply(', '.join).reset_index()
df.head()
```

Comment: @RafaelC he wants the column in it though. I don't think there's an alternative

Comment: Yeah, there are some information missing on this question indeed